# Convert CHM to PDF in batch?

Tags: ubuntu, conversion

Is there a good program or script to convert many chm files to pdf with good quality? (Preferably suitable for computer or iPad viewing)

Info:

Operating System: Ubuntu 13.10

Answer (score 1):

CHM is abbreviation of "**C** ompiled **H** T **M** L Help" for this reason you need chm decompiler first:

1. Chmlib for install it execute: `sudo apt-get install libchm-bin`
2. htmldoc for install it execute `sudo apt-get install htmldoc`

You need to convert CHM to HTML first by executing `extract_chmLib book.chm outdir`.Now execute `htmldoc` command to converting HTML to PDF.

Reference: http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-convert-chm-files-to-html-or-pdf-files.html

or use online websites like: https://cloudconvert.org/chm-to-pdf